# change linewidth in chord plot

Tags: python, plot, chord-diagram

I want to plot a chord plot like the following:

[image]

With chord linewidth = some value associated with each chord.
Curently am using an example [taken from here](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/406-chord-diagram_mne), however I am unable to modify linewidth.

- how do i modify linewith?
- is there another library that can work?

```py
# pip install mne_connectivity
from mne_connectivity.viz import plot_connectivity_circle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N = 8
node_names = [f"N{i}" for i in range(N)]
con = np.random.rand(N,N)
fig, axes = plot_connectivity_circle(con, node_names,colormap='Blues',
    facecolor='white', textcolor='black', 
    linewidth=10 )  #### CONTROL LINEWIDTH HERE 
fig.show()
```